# Generate nonce with Google Cloud Functions for CSP

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nonce, content-security-policy

I have a website hosted on firebase. I want to enforce a CSP that requires a nonce value for running scripts. I am also using Google Cloud Functions. I have a nonce generating function and I'm able to generate nonces. It seems to me that my function is unable to read the index.html file however I am stuck as to why. Can someone help me figure out what is going on?

I checked to makes sure the packages I am importing are installed.

My file structure is this:
-public
--index.html
-functions
--nonceGeneratingFunction.js

Line 16 is triggered when I access the function's endpoint.

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

functions.http('test', (req, res) => {
    // Generate nonce value
    const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('hex');
    
    // Read the index.html file
    const indexHtmlPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html');

    fs.readFile(indexHtmlPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error reading index.html:', err);
          res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
          return;
        }

    // Set the response headers
    res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', `script-src 'nonce-${nonce}' 'strict-dynamic'`);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Allow requests from any origin
    
    // Replace the nonce placeholder in the index.html file with the actual nonce value
    const modifiedHtml = data.replace('${nonce}', nonce);

    // Send the modified index.html file content as the response
    res.send(modifiedHtml);
    });
});
```

I checked to make sure that everything is set up by returning a 200 OK status. That was successful so then I tried to generate the nonce and display it. That was also successful. Now I am trying to read a file and I was expecting that I would be able to read it, and then through the rest of the code, modify the variable I reference in the file as well as the CSP headers.